# ImageView com tamanhos para todas as telas

Tags: swift

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para iOS usando o Swift 4. O que tenho quebrado a cabeça é em relação aos tamanhos das telas.

Vejo que o Auto Layout ajuda em alguns casos, dentre eles, disposição dos elementos em Retrato e Paisagem.

Mas tenho um problema que parece ser simples, mas estou meio confuso:

Tenho uma imagem que será a Logo e ficaria na parte de cima, centralizada. Quando coloco em uma resolução no iPhone 4s fica de uma forma, no iPhone 7 outra e assim por diante.

Mesmo eu mexendo nas constraints, a imagem fica muito pequena no iPad. Como faria para redimensionar também a imagem e os components conforme a resolução da tela do dispositivo?

Answer (score 1):

Você quer que a imagem aumente proporcionalmente, de acordo com o dispositivo?

Acredito que se você colocar pra manter a resolução (aspect fill ou aspect fit) na imagem, e também, ao colocar as constraints (pelo menos 3 constraints na imagem) selecionar a opção "Aspect Ratio" ela aumenta ou diminui, de acordo com o tamanho do dispositivo, mantendo sua proporção e resolução.

Não sei se é isso, mas espero ter ajudado mano.